# Performance: Comparing two lists in python for string matches

Tags: python, regex, performance

What is the most efficient way to compare two lists and only keep the elements that are in list A but not B for very large datasets?

Example:

```
words = ['shoe brand', 'car brand', 'smoothies for everyone', ...]
filters = ['brand', ...]
# Matching function
results = ['smoothies for everyone']
```

There have been [somewhat similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295827/comparing-the-items-of-two-lists-in-python/16295946?noredirect=1#comment23327770_16295946) but I'm currently dealing with 1M+ words and filters, leading to Regular Expressions overloads. I used to do a simple 'filters[i] in words[j]' test with while-loops, but this seems awfully inefficient.

Comment: Use a `set()`, the lookups will be faster.

Comment: You say it *seems* inefficient, but *is* it? If it is, you can avoid matching regexps for *all* entries by using a hash function - only compare the entries the hashes of which match.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: Set does not check if strings contain, they just to exact matches, see example

Comment: @mfukar: In this case I wouldn't even need regex - ' '+filter+' ' in ' '+word+' ' would do. Still, this takes forever but if it's the most efficient I will have to deal with it :)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I thought you meant complete matches. My comment obviously doesn't apply.

Comment: I would use precompiled regexs for filters. Maybe you can post your code and we can try to find your bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried slightly modified @gnibbler version: it is using set operation **intersection** instead of list comprehension. I believe that this version is a bit faster.

```
>>> words = ['shoe brand', 'car brand', 'smoothies for everyone']
>>> filters = {'brand'}
>>> [w for w in words if not set(w.split()).intersection(filters)]
['smoothies for everyone']
```

Comment: Do you have a benchmark for the set intersection actually being faster? I would assume that the set construction is a bit expensive (hashes need to be calculated).

Comment: I just tested both versions by timeit.Timer(test).timeit(), my run a bit faster 3 times, but that should be tested on large dataset ... :(

Comment: My idea was that list comprehension/iteration is slower than library function ... but yeah, you are correct too.

Comment: I tested it against [the english San Francisco wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco), using the sentences (``words=f.read().lower().split('.')``). ``filters={'city', 'bay'}``. The set version runs in 0.007 seconds per run and the list version in 0.009 seconds per run. [My test source](http://fpaste.org/74566/). Interestingly, with python2, the code is faster, but the relative difference is approximately (1:1.19 vs. 1:1.25) the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can make filters a set

```
>>> words = ['shoe brand', 'car brand', 'smoothies for everyone']
>>> filters = {'brand'}
>>> [w for w in words if all(i not in filters for i in w.split())]
['smoothies for everyone']
```

This works *better* than your `filters[i] in words[j]` because it won't filter "smoothies" if "smooth" is in the filter list

Comment: Interesting approach, although your concern should be avoided by including spaces in filters and words (' '+word+' '). I will try which one is faster! Thanks!